# use ggplot/qplot to plot multiple lines in a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using qplot in ggplot2 to plot two columns (a score from two tests) against eachother. this is fine. however when i add a third column saying which group each score came from (age group), I do not know how to plot a line for each group.

my data looks like:

```
test1     test2     age_band
-----     -----     --------
```

I currently have:

```
qplot(score1,score2,data=mydata,geom="smooth")
```

Looking at the qplot documentation it isn't clear to me that there is a parameter which can partition my plots using the age_band column.

How do I do this?

Comment: I think the following should do the job `group = age_band`

Comment: @Jack Ryan - it's a scatter plot for each age_band, but drawing a line of best fit through each scatter plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that adding the group parameter to qplot should work perfectly.

```
qplot(score1,score2,data=mydata,group=age_band,geom="smooth")
```